# Ошибка "C1014: слишком много включаемых файлов"

Tags: c++

Привет всем. У меня вопрос. Начал учить С++ Conlose Application. У меня проект, в нём есть 2 файла: main.cpp и hello.cpp. И в первом я прописал вызов hello.cpp. Но пишет ошибку

> `1>c:\users\владик\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\myfirstprogramm\myfirstprogramm\hello.cpp(2): fatal error C1014: слишком много включаемых файлов: глубина = 1024
> 1>  hello.cpp
> 1>c:\users\владик\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\myfirstprogramm\myfirstprogramm\hello.cpp(2): fatal error C1014: слишком много включаемых файлов: глубина = 1024
> 1>  Создание кода...`

Код в 1 программе

```
#include <iostream>
#include "hello.cpp"

int main()
{
    Hello.cpp();
    return 0;
}
```

А в hello.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "hello.cpp"

int main() hellow.cpp void hellow()
{

    printf("Hellow");
}
```

В чём ошибка? Это урок по видео. Вот [ссылка](http://cplus-plus.ru/video-on-c-online/fundamentals-of-cpp/947-lekciya-1-programma-sostoyaschaya-iz-neskolkih-faylov-kompilyaciya-i-linkovka.html).

Comment: @RconPro, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 3):

Обычно все начинают заголовочные файлы (обычно это .h) (в общем то, что подключается #include) так:

```
#ifndef MY_FILE_123_H
#define MY_FILE_123_H
 ....
#endif
```

Это предотвращает зацикливание, да и просто обеспечивает однократную подстановку кода.

Иногда (например в stdlib.h или stdio.h #define делаются хитре, в зависимости от ряда условий)

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в том, что директивой препроцессора `#include` вы подключаете hello.cpp. Подключаяя hello.cpp из hello.cpp, вы получаете рекурсию, которую препроцессор обрубает после 1024 вложенных включений.

А в видео автор (кстати, знакомые всё лица - привет Евгению Линскому!) создает отдельный заголовочный файл hello.h, в котором размещает прототип функции из hello.cpp. Так что следите за уроком внимательнее!

Comment: Млин, ну когда же все будут преподавать С как он - через линь и gcc?!!!

Comment: Ради интереса взял  и посмотрел эту лекцию от начала до конца. Реально 80% времени пустая писанина на доске. Неужели так сейчас в институтах учат ? Впрочем, у нас наверное было примерно также.

--

Естественно, что потом у студентов такое непонимание.

Comment: @mikillskegg, все - не скоро, но тенденция налицо.

Comment: И сбудется это, когда C по распространённости сравняется с PL/I.

Comment: IMHO программ на C порядка на два больше, чем на PL/I, который, кстати, язык весьма неудачный (по крайней мере сейчас так воспринимается). 

До знакомства с C я писал на нем (EC ЭВМ и VAX/VMS).

Comment: А сколько на C новых проектов? Думаю всё же он будет заменяться языками высокого уровня. А pl/i -- рождественская ёлка, на которую "большой голубой" с друзьям (IBM Users Society) навесили всё, что под руку попалось к середине 60х.

Comment: Так, для справки: http://www.blackducksoftware.com/osrc/data/projects/#languageos

Это, разумеется, по опенсорсу (там более менее реально посчитать). Для закрытого кода предположительно в тройке C++, Java и C#. Но точных данных нет, а всяким индексам типа TIOBE очень сложно верить, учитывая их методологию сбора данных.

Comment: И Си, и С++ в обозримом будущем определенно будут занимать свою нишу, притом далеко не маргинальную, поскольку для этой ниши альтернатив пока не предвидится.

Comment: @northerner, очень интересная табличка. 

Интересно также какой процент из С++ проектов **действительно** крестовые, а сколько из них по сути сишные (без ООП заморочек), но вынуждено  используют что-то  из крестовых библиотек.

Comment: @mikillskegg ви таки оптимист или пессимист? (Про c-- в качестве альтернативы c в роли backend'а промолчим). @avp C++ -- не только ООП, но и ценный мех, пардон шаблоны, включая stl(кстати сам Степанов, говорят, об ООП отзывался не очень уважительно). И уж вопрос совсем не по теме: в VMS-11 русские буквы как кодировались -- КОИ-7?

Comment: @alexlz, насколько помню, да КОИ-7 а символ переключения между кодировками уже забыл. stl я в основном и имел ввиду, когда говорил о библиотеках. Кто такой Степанов ? Во взглядах на ООП он видимо не одинок.

Comment: Ну если КОИ-7, значит объяснять термин "монгольский текст" не надо. А Степанов -- автор stl (он ещё в шутку в интервью каким-то итальянцам сказал, что STL расшифровывается как Степанов и Ли -- его помощница)

Answer (score 0):

Простите, Вы из main.cpp вызываете файл hello.cpp? Может вы хотите функцию вызвать, прописанную в этом файле? Я что-то не пойму что делает строчка hello.cpp().

**Добавлено из комментария**.

```
//main.cpp
#include "hello.cpp"
int main()
{
    hellow();
    return 0;
}

//hello.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
void hellow()
{
    printf("Hellow");
}
```

Comment: Я хочу из меин вызвать Хелло.срр

Comment: Сделайте пожалуйста форматный вид кодов файлов

Comment: А `return 0;` добавить не надо?

Comment: hellow() типа void. Она ничего не возвращает